# Using JavaScript to render forms dynamically in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

So I am new to Django and a complete novice at JavaScript. I am trying to create a view which renders multiple forms dynamically using JavaScript. Below are two forms that I have created.

```
class CreateTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Test
    fields = ['name', 'test_group', 'description', 'query_text', 'failure_condition', 'status']

def getKey(self):
    return "create_test_form"

class VC1Form(CreateTestForm):
expected_relation = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [('<','<'), ('>','>'), ('=','='), ('<=','<='), ('>=','>='), ('!=','!=')], required = True, label = 'Expected Relation: ')
num_rows = forms.IntegerField()

def getKey(self):
    return "vc1_form"
```

In addition, I have the following view

```
def create_test(request):
context = {
    'all_validation_classes': ValidationClass.objects.all()
}
for form in [CreateTestForm, VC1Form]:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f=form(request.POST)
        if (f.is_valid()):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/test_created/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/test_not_created/')
    else:
        f = form()
    context[f.getKey()] = f
return render(request, 'create_test.html', context)
```

And template:

```
<form action="/tests/create/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{{create_test_form.as_ul}} <br><br>

<select id="validation_classes_id" name="all_validation_classes" onchange="showForm()">
    <option value="%">Choose the validation class</option>
    {% for val_class in all_validation_classes %}
     <option value="{{ val_class.id }}">{{ val_class.id}}  {{val_class.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<br><br>


<script>
    function showForm(){
        var x = document.getElementById("validation_class_id").value;
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I am trying to get to a point, where, when the user selects something from the dropdown (validation_classes_id), the view will render the form corresponding to that selection. I have currently included only one additional form VC1Form here but I have written different forms corresponding to each option in the drop down. 
I have tried a few things but nothing has worked yet and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you would use [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: Don't Formsets work only when you want to dynamically display the same form multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Try something this:

`document.getElementById('form').querySelectorAll("label").forEach( e =>
        {e.prepend(document.createElement("br"));});`

Even better would be:

```
<form id="form" action="login_view" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form }}
  </table>
    <input type="submit" value="register">
```